# Разница в смысле в вопросах Кто это? Это кто?

Tags: порядок-слов

как известно, в русском языке порядок слов зависит от того, что хотят подчеркнуть. Не могу для себя четко сформулировать, в чем разница в вопросах кто это и это кто. Кто-нибудь может помочь?

с уважением,

Анна

Answer (score 2):

"Кто это?" — вариант более нейтральный. Примерно равен варианту *А кто это?*
"Это кто?" — вариант более императивный, грозный или (отчасти) брезгливый. Примерно равен варианту *Это ещё кто?!*

Comment: большое спасибо